# Controller ModelState with ModelStateWrappper

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection

HI, to all, i am use Structure Map to implement dependency-injection. I created ModelStateWrapper class to send Model state in service layer, which in constructor get reference to ModelState of controller. In bootswrapper i registered my type:

```
ForRequestedType<ISourceService>()
            .TheDefaultIsConcreteType<SourceService>();
ForRequestedType<IValidationDictionary>()
        .TheDefaultIsConcreteType<ModelStateWrapper>();
```

How i can give reference of controller's model state to ModelStateWrapper here ?

p.s. sorry for my english :)

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/models-data/validating-with-a-service-layer-cs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to provide more information, but this is my best guess as to what you have:

```
public class ModelStateWrapper : IValidationDictionary
{
    ...
     private readonly ModelState _modelState;
     public ModelStateWrapper(ModelState modelState)
     {
          _modelState = modelState;
     }
    ...
}
```

If you want to pass a variable (the controller's model state in this case) to the ModelStateWrapper you almost certainly need to do that explicitly by calling the ObjectFactory.

Example:

```
MyController : Controller 
{
   ...
   public MyAction()
   {
      ...
      IValidationDictionary validationDictionary = ObjectFactory
          .With<ModelState>(this.ModelState)
          .GetInstance<IValidationDictionary>();
      ...
   }
   ...
}
```

See this documentation for details:

[Passing Arguments to StructureMap at Runtime](http://structuremap.sourceforge.net/RetrievingServices.htm#section5)

Comment: Thanks for reply, yes i have this situation and i want to set ModelState of controller to IValidationDictionary in Bootswrapper file, not in controller. Can I do this? Or i need to set in on my own base controller class ?